# Help setting up NGINX

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup a proxy server using nginx. The server is running Windows Server 2003 and running IIS and tomcat. 
What I'm trying to achieve is to redirect call say from sma.local.com:80 to the internal server that is on servername.domain.com:8080/orderpad.

This is my first time dealing with nginx and I'm a bit frustrated with it.
NGINX config

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  sma.local.com;


    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass sservername.domain.com:8080/orderpad;
        #proxy_set_header   Host    servername.domain.com:8080/orderpad;
        #proxy_set_header   X-Host  servername.domain.com:8080/orderpad;
        #proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to access the sma.local.com address.

Comment: Belongs to ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

You can be redirected to your upstream server like this :

http {
    upstream myserver {
    sservername.domain.com:8080;
      }

server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  sma.local.com;

access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://myserver/orderpad;
    }

Answer (score 0):

don't you have to have the full "http://..." URI in your proxy pass?

Example:
[Nginx LoadBalance Example](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxLoadBalanceExample)

EDIT: Oh and if you wanted URIs such as /orderpad/testthing, then you need the trailing slash '/' otherwise it'll end up as /orderpadtestthing